# Nav Bar and Footer Unalign on Mobile View - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a menu bar through bootstrap that when the window width is smaller, the nav turns into a button menu. When the window width is made smaller, the button on the right is pushed down and not aligned with the logo on the left.

For the footer, I created two columns using `col-md-6` and applied `text-align: left, text-align: right` to each column since they were not off to the side. Now when the window width is smaller, the same thing happens: the text/column on the right is pushed down and not aligned with the text on the left.

Both the nav and footer do not vertically align properly. I've tried setting a negative margin-top on both the button and text that are being pushed down; I've also tried using `pull-left` and `pull-right` and that made no difference either. I also have no media queries but I'm not sure if that is an issue.

Here is an example and the code: http://jsfiddle.net/w92w4dak/

Any ideas on how to vertically align the nav/footer properly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.navbar-toggle` button needs to be inside the `.navbar-header` div to achieve the desired vertical alignment.

The footer columns should have the class `.col-xs-6` instead of `.col-sm-6` to ensure they stay as 50% of the screen width at all screen sizes (including mobile view)

Comment: perfect, thanks. i didn't think it would be so simple